# From where do the encodings supported by Terminal come?

Tags: macos, terminal

If one goes into the Preferences of Terminal.app, there is an "Encodings" tab.  From where does this list come?  How can one add further encodings?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the encodings menu you should see "Customize List".  Select that and it will give you the full list of 100 or so available.  Is what you need not on that?

A reference for Apple's Text Encoding Converter, which probably provides this function, is at

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/Text_Encodin_sion_Manager/Text_Encodin_sion_Manager.pdf

iconv includes ucs-2 in case that is of any use:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/iconv_open.3.html

Comment: I think you're referring to the "Character encoding" drop-down under "International" on the "Settings > Advanced" tab (at least on Mountain Lion 10.8.5)?  The "Customize Encodings List..." option at the bottom of that control takes me to the "Encodings" tab to which my question refers (the list to which I would like to add further encodings).

Comment: Yes, and my Encodings tab has about 100 scrollable choices with check boxes.  What is it you could need to add to that, if it were possible?  Is yours truncated?

Comment: I need UCS-2, rather than UTF-16.

Comment: Aha. Will UTF-16 not work?  It is essentially the same, just covers more characters, those beyond the BMP, which are pretty rare for most users.  I have added a reference to the TEC, in case that helps.

Comment: One imagines that, if UTF-16 would work, I wouldn't have asked the question... but in any event, I might as well have asked about a custom encoding.  My question was "**From where does this list come?**" and "**How can one add further encodings?**", neither of which are addressed by your answer.  -1

Comment: You might want to just say "How can I add UCS-2 to this list?" in your original question.  Or also elaborate a bit on why you need it, in case someone knows of another way to approach the problem than trying to add an encoding to the TEC or whatever does this function.